# pass arguments to running C app

Tags: c, linux, command-line-arguments

I am writing small C program which will act like daemon and do something every second. I managed it to run only single instance using filelock and last thing I need to know is if it is possible to send commandline arguments to running program, something like that:

first program start:

```
./sampleprogram
```

then decide to take some action/update setting

```
./sampleprogram -r
```

it will be another rotation script for my thinkpad X41 convertible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
/*#include <stdbool.h>*/
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define NIL -1

int fdlock;
int get_lock(void)
{
    struct flock fl;
    fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    fl.l_start = 0;
    fl.l_len = 1;
    if((fdlock = open("oneproc.lock", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666)) == -1) { return 0; }
    if(fcntl(fdlock, F_SETLK, &fl) == -1) { return 0; }
    return 1;
}


int main() {

    if(!get_lock()) {
        fputs("Process already running!\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    int tabletmode;
    int autorotate = TRUE;
    int prevmode = NIL;
    FILE *fstate;
    char state[1];
    FILE *fgyrovals;
    char gyroval_a[1];

    while (TRUE) {
        fstate = fopen("/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/hotkey_tablet_mode", "r");
        fread(state, sizeof(state[0]), 1, fstate);
        /*
        printf("picaa");
        fflush(stdout);
        */
        /*tabletmode = atoi(state[0]);*/
        tabletmode = state[0] - '0';
        printf("koko: %d", tabletmode);
        fflush(stdout);
        fclose(fstate);

        if (prevmode != tabletmode) {
            if (tabletmode) {
                system("notify-send 'Notebook v tablet móde'");
            } else {
                system("notify-send 'Notebook v štandartnom režime'");
            }
        }

        if (tabletmode) {
            if (autorotate) {
                fgyrovals = fopen("/sys/devices/platform/hdaps/position", "r");
                fclose(fgyrovals);
            }
        }           

        prevmode = tabletmode;

        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One way to do this is to have your program check a file (or a pipe) periodically and change its behavior based on the contents.

Comment: I was tinking about this solution but I am running system from a CF card using IDE-2-CF reduction (which is much much paster than original 1,8" IDE) and writing or reading state informations from file every second for example should have impact to lifetime of memory space in card

Comment: Why not opening IPC sockets in a partition mounted in RAM?

Comment: Use an Unix domain datagram socket, typical path would be `/var/run/sampleprogram.socket` (alongside `/var/run/sampleprogram.pid` as your program lock). You only "write" the socket metadata to card, and only when initially creating the socket, so it does not affect card lifetime in any meaningful way. Each datagram is a full set of "command-line parameters", separated with ASCII NULs (`\0`). This is quite simple to implement, too. Need example code?

Comment: You could use signals.  See http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html

Comment: A client-server architecture, where if your program is already started a client send the CLI argument to your server is what I would do